# Django sorting by column number

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to sort results by column number, not using column name. Falling back to raw sql:

```
mytable.objects.raw('select * from hub_endu order by 1 desc')
```

Can I achieve this on django ORM ?

like

```
mytable.objects.order_by("-1")
```

Answer (score 2):

you could override the queryset of your model, and convert indexes to field names

```
class CustomQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def order_by(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_args = []
        for arg in args:
            if type(arg) == int:
                my_args.append(self.model._meta.fields[arg].name)
            else:
                my_args.append(arg)

        print my_args
        return super(CustomQuerySet, self).order_by(*my_args, **kwargs)

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return CustomQuerySet(self.model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended courtesy of http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/12/27/sql-server-order-by-columnname-vs-order-by-columnnumber/

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
-- ColumnName (Recommended)
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Department
ORDER BY GroupName, Name
GO
-- ColumnNumber (Strongly Not Recommended)
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Department
ORDER BY 3,2
GO
```